# Woocommerce Duplicate product then increment highest SKU

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Using woocommerce hook as follow :

I am expecting with the query $queryLast to get latest product SKU,

BUT

get_the_ID() always returns the duplicated items even with :

```
wp_reset_postdata();
wp_reset_query();
clean_post_cache(get_the_ID());
```

I need to get item ID requested in queryLast.

To illustrate, let's say my highest SKU is 1600, i am duplicating SKU 300.
Expected behavior is to assign new SKU 1601 to the new product ( SKU 300 duplication )

Now it does assign new SKU to 301...etc

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_duplicate', 'duplicate_sku_func', 10, 2 ); 

function duplicate_sku_func( $duplicate ) {

if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
    return;
}

$product_id = $duplicate->save(); 
wp_reset_postdata();
wp_reset_query();
clean_post_cache(get_the_ID());

$args = array(
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'orderby' => 'id' , 
    'post_type'=> 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => 1 ,
);

$queryLast = new WP_Query($args);

while ( $queryLast->have_posts() ) : $queryLast->the_post();
  $sku2 = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_sku', true );
  //$your_sku = get_the_ID();
  $your_sku = (int) $sku2+1;
endwhile;


  update_post_meta($product_id, '_sku', $your_sku );  
  update_post_meta($product_id, '_manage_stock', 'yes');
  update_post_meta($product_id, '_stock', '1');   

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the hook `woocommerce_product_duplicate` is called after duplicate product saved. So, definitely you are getting new duplicate product sku value which is from parent sku 300 not the last product sku 1600. Because the last inserted product sku is now 301 and you are getting that. 
So, Replace your codes with follows snippet -

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_duplicate_before_save', 'duplicate_sku_func', 10, 2 ); 

function duplicate_sku_func( $duplicate, $product ) {

    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
        return;
    }

    $args = array(
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'orderby' => 'id' , 
        'post_type'=> 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => 1 ,
        'fields'        => 'ids'
    );

    $queryLast = new WP_Query($args);
    $your_sku = '';
    if( $queryLast->get_posts() ) {
        foreach ( $queryLast->get_posts() as $product_id) {
            $sku2 = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_sku', true );
            $your_sku = (int) $sku2+1;
        }
    }
    $duplicate->set_sku( $your_sku );
    $duplicate->set_manage_stock( 'yes' );
    $duplicate->set_stock_quantity( 1 );

}
```

Comment: @itzmekhotan thanks, but : abstract-wc-product.php(816): WC_Data->error('product_invalid...', 'UGS non valide ...', 400, Array)\n#1 /var/www/wp-content/themes/easy-commerce/functions.php(119): WC_Product->set_sku('1')  Actually SKU is going to be set to 1 always and returns a duplicate error

Comment: had a bad sequence in my SKU, your code works great !